# Web service array size limit

Tags: .net, web-services, arrays, configuration

My web method kept faulting and investigations eventually revealed the following:

> The formatter threw an exception while
>   trying to deserialize the message:
>   Error in deserializing body of request
>   message for operation 'SendFirmware'.
>   The maximum array length quota (16384)
>   has been exceeded while reading XML
>   data. This quota may be increased by
>   changing the MaxArrayLength property
>   on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
>   object used when creating the XML
>   reader.

The array in question is a `byte[]` containing the firmware image mentioned in the method name. This is why it has so many elements. OK, marvellous, now I know what's wrong, and if I were explicitly managing the XML it wouldn't be a problem. But I'm not, it's all implicit.

How does one set this in the config file for a web service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be set in the web.config file in the  section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8388608" 
               maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
               maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```